# Массив значений скрытых полей jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый день! Динамически создаются <input type="hidden" value="<any text>">
как мне можно получить все данные скрытых полей в массив?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var arrayOfHiddenValues = $('input[type="hidden"]').map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

- [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

$('input:hidden');
$("input[type='hidden']");
Почитайте про [селекторы](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Лучше прочитайте вопрос

Answer (score 0):

получаем массив скрытых полей input

var all=$(":input :hidden");

далее делаетет цикл, в котром работаете с отдельным элементом